# strcpy giving me segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have code which is giving me a segmentation fault. I debugged it and and the error occurred when the strcpy executed. The code is attempting to extract data from a text file and store it into an array of structs. I plan to use strcpy to store the store the text file's data into the structs. Any idea why this is occurring?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int input( char *s, int length);

void main(){

    char *tok;
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters;
    FILE *f;
    char *file_name;
    char line[255];
    int currentRoom;
    int count = 0;
    typedef struct {
        char room_n;
        char description[100];
        char room_north;
        char room_south;
        char room_west;
        char room_east;
    } room;

    //Creating an array of structs
    room record[1000];
    while(1){

        buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));


        if(buffer == NULL){
            perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter a command: ");
        characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);

        if(strcmp(buffer,"exit\n") == 0){
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        tok = strtok(buffer, " \n"); // Tokenize input
        printf("%s is the token \n", tok);


        if (strcmp(tok,"loaddungeon") == 0){
            file_name = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            printf("file name : %s \n", file_name);
            f = fopen(file_name,"r");
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != NULL)
                {

                    char val1[128];
                    char val2[128];
                    char val3[128];
                    char val4[128];
                    char val5[128];
                    char val6[128];

                    strcpy(val1, strtok(line, "$"));
                    strcpy(val2, strtok(NULL, "$"));
                    strcpy(val3, strtok(NULL, " "));
                    strcpy(val4, strtok(NULL, " "));
                    strcpy(val5, strtok(NULL, " "));
                    strcpy(val6, strtok(NULL, " "));

                    //Segmentation fault error occurs here
                    strcpy(record[count].room_n, val1);
```

Comment: The arguments to `strcpy()` must be `char*`. `room_n` is `char`.

Comment: You should have gotten a compiler warning about that line. Don't ignore warnings.

Comment: I changed the line in the struct from char room_n to char* room_n and no longer get warning but still get seg fault.

Comment: Have you allocated memory for `room_n` to point to?

Comment: Why don't you declare it as `char room_n[128]`?

Comment: Thank you Barmar, it works now. Still new to low level programming so this is a learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of strcpy() is:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
```

where-

- dest -- This is the pointer to the destination array where the
  content is to be copied.
- src -- This is the string to be copied.

In your code arguments passed to strcpy() is `char` and `char *` :

```
strcpy(record[count].room_n, val1);
```

As defined in the structure:

```
typedef struct {
        char room_n;  //room_n declared as 'char'
        char description[100];
        char room_north;
        char room_south;
        char room_west;
        char room_east;
    } room;
```

Suggestion:

Allocate memory for `room_n` to point to. Change the declaration to
`char room_n[128];`

Comment: Hi.. added the changes as suggested by @Barmar.. Thanks!